# Problem while eliminating some rows in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table like this

[image]

I want to eliminate all rows which code RM with reason 54 and 55.

NB: I should not eliminate the last row.

My code change is:

```
select * 
from table 
where code!='RM' and reason not in('54','55')
```

But it is not giving the correct output. Some rows are missing in my output.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: change `!=` to `<>`

Comment: They 're the same in T-SQL @deHaar [Functions the same as the <> (Not Equal To) comparison operator.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/not-equal-to-transact-sql-exclamation?view=sql-server-ver15). The only difference is that `<>` is SQL-92 standard  and `!=` not.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for your case

> select *  from table  where NOT (code='RM' and reason IN ('54','55'))

Answer (score 0):

The "not equals" operator in t-sql is `<>` rather than `!=`.

That said, I like CodeNinja's answer more if you only want to eliminate reasons 54 and 55 in the case of the RM code.